# Symfony2: An easy way to clean cache and set permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, symfony

When I update my Symfony2 project I always have to do this:

```
root@xxx:/var/www/project# php app/console cache:clear --env=prod 
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug true
root@xxx:/var/www/project# chmod -R 777 app/cache
root@xxx:/var/www/project# chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

Is there an easier way to do it? Or can I permanently set the permissions on ubuntu? How do you do it? (I am using Komodo as editor, I could put a macro button in there that remotely cleans my cache or use Eclipse, but I have my issues with eclipse)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the [Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) properly, there is no need to set permissions of `cache` and `logs` directories after running `cache:clear` command

Comment: Thanks ferhad! Any hint for not having to go the console, connect ssl and typing it in?